# Get tkinter Entry to validate final state, skip intermediary deletions?

Tags: python, validation, tkinter, tkinter-entry

So if I want to restrict a value to be between 100 and 200...

```
import tkinter as tk

master = tk.Tk()

def validatePLZ(index, value_if_allowed):
    print("validatePLZ with index:%s and proposed value:%s" % (index, value_if_allowed))
    if int(index) > 3 or len(value_if_allowed) > 3:
        return False
    print("Not too long")
    value = int(value_if_allowed)
    print("Considering value: ", value)
    if value < 100 or value > 200:
        return False
    return True

vcmd = (master.register(validatePLZ), '%i', '%P')
ent = tk.Entry(master, validate="key", validatecommand=vcmd)
ent.insert(0, "150")
ent.pack()

tk.Button(master, text="Validate").pack()

tk.mainloop()
```

This has worked in less strict conditions, where zero was allowed, but if the value is '150' and I am trying to change to '170' by highlighting '5' and typing '7' what I see is:

1. Deletion of '5' with a result of '10'
2. Addition of '7', after failed deletion, with a result of '1570'

But it fails on #1 so it is not working.  I do still want #1 to happen if just deleting a character, but how can the highlight-replace be combined into one check?  Or how do I know if it is a highlight-replace and not simply a deletion?

Comment: I can't change 5 to 7.

Comment: That's the problem @toyotaSupra =D  I added some prints to better show what is happening and why the value cannot be changed.

Comment: This method of validation simply can't work. You must either allow invalid numbers, or do the validation in some other way such as on focus out or when the user clicks a button or presses return.

Comment: @Bryan Oakley. **OP wants a value to be between 100 and 200**. As you said in your comment, the answer is no! **The user doesn't have to click a button**. Please see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

> This has worked in less strict conditions, where zero was allowed, but
> if the value is '150' and I am trying to change to '170' by
> highlighting '5' and typing '7' what I see is:
>
> Deletion of '5' with a result of '10'
>
> Addition of '7', after failed deletion, with a result of '1570'
>
> But it fails on #1 so it is not working. I do still want #1 to happen
> if just deleting a character, but how can the highlight-replace be
> combined into one check? Or how do I know if it is a highlight-replace
> and not simply a deletion?

The problem can be fixed.

- On line 8, change `return False`  to `return True`.
- On line 12, change `or` to `and` boolean change  `> 200` to  `< 200`.

Snippet:

```
def validatePLZ(index, value_if_allowed):
    print("validatePLZ with index:%s and proposed value:%s" % (index, value_if_allowed))
    if int(index) > 3 or len(value_if_allowed) > 3:
        return True
    print("Not too long")
    value = int(value_if_allowed)
    print("Considering value: ", value)
    if value < 100 and value < 200:
        return False
    return True
```

Screenshot at first start:

[image]

Screenshot. Place cursor at the end and use backspace to delete:

[image]

Screenshot. After deleting backspace you can see in debug to print 15:

[image]

Screenshot. Place cursor between 5 and 0 and use backspace to delete. You can see in debug to print 10:

[image]

Screenshot. Enter 7 between 5 and 0. You can see in debug to print 1570: .

[image]

Screenshot. Highlight 5 to delete. You can see in debug to print 170:

After that, the user cannot enter the `Entry` widget.

[image]

Hopefully, if this is what you want,